# animate elements depending on class name

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, traversal

I have an unordered list containing two div's(referred to as .card and .slot) I would like to have the .card animate, one at a time (i.e. the first .card clicked will animate to a raised height. Clicking on the next '.card' will animate the first back to its original height. the idea being only one '.card' is set w/ raised height.

I thought to give the currently clicked '.card' a class ('.current'), added to each new onclick event (removed from remaining ('.cards'). then traverse through the list of '.cards' to animate the current clicked and reset any others.

but I am having trouble. if anyone can point me in the right direction i would appreciate it.

here is code example

http://pastebin.com/XsswqCsU

Thank you !

Free Mike Tyson !

Comment: i realize in haste i forgot to open the script tag in my example. when testing you'll need to add that guy back in there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand your use of card and slot, but you can use code generally like this (which can be adapted to your particular HTML):

```
<ul>
<li><div class="card">Card 1</div><div class="slot"></div></li>
<li><div class="card">Card 2</div><div class="slot"></div></li>
<li><div class="card">Card 3</div><div class="slot"></div></li>
<li><div class="card">Card 4</div><div class="slot"></div></li>
</ul>​

$(".card").click(function() {
    var this$ = $(this);
    var slot$ = this$.closest("li").find(".slot");
    if (!slot$.hasClass("expanded")) {
        this$.closest("ul").find(".expanded")
            .removeClass("expanded")
            .animate({height: "20px"});
        slot$.addClass("expanded").animate({height: "200px"});
    }
});​
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Bc73Y/

Comment: thanks for your reply. i am looking at your solution.   here is my code in action. http://jsfiddle.net/KfGNN/3/ , if you click on the card (white boxes) you will see the effect. my problem is I only want the focused box to be animated on click event, the remaining to be reset to initial position.

Comment: To start with `var $this = $(this)` must be inside the click handler function, not where you have it.